# How do I grant super user permission to fileinputstream object and read all system files on my rooted device

Tags: android

I have a rooted device I am trying to read files from a specific folder */sdcard/videos* using **FileInputStream** and successfully created a CHECKSUM value for that folder, Now I want to read all the files from my system folder and create a checksum value for it but when I pass the folder path which is */system* I am unable to read few files and get the following error:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: system/bin/run-as: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How do I overcome this, how do I grant super user permission or root access to read all the system related files ?

Simplified: Programatically Read file from *sdcard/system* folder using fileinputstream on rooted device

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried it yet

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
//from here all commands are executed with su permissions
stdin.writeBytes("md5sum filepath"); 
   /* executes the md5sum binary command,replace with installation path of md5sum after you install busybox */
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_LEN];
int read;
String out = new String();
//read method will wait forever if there is nothing in the stream
//so we need to read it in another way than while((read=stdout.read(buffer))>0)
while(true){
    read = stdout.read(buffer);
    out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
    if(read<BUFF_LEN){
        //we have read everything
        break;
    }
}
```

Create checksum by calling the `md5sum` binary
ie. If you have [BusyBox](https://www.busybox.net/) installed on your device

Comment: isn't there a way without copying because I perform this operation every five minutes and send the checksum value to the server so this is not a good idea i guess